# Powershell: multiple wildcards in Get-ChildItem path

Tags: powershell, wildcard, directory-structure, ls, get-childitem

I'm trying to use `Get-ChildItem` in powershell (I'm using the `ls` alias) to return only files within a specific folder structure.

As an example, say I'm trying to list all files whose names end in `.foobar.txt` that reside within a folder called `src`, which in turn resides in a folder called `even`. I've tried using the command `ls -r *\even\src\*.foobar.txt | % FullName`. I thought the first wildcard `*` in the path would allow any path that ends in `\even\src\` and that the second one would match only files that end in `.foobar.txt`. But it isn't returning all the files I expect. Here's the structure of the directory I'm testing it in:

```
root
|- project1
|  |- odd
|     |- src
|     |  |- a.foobar.txt
|     |  |- b.foobar.txt
|     |  |- c.snafu.txt
|     |
|     |- temp
|        |- a.foobar.txt
|        |- b.foobar.txt
|        |- c.snafu.txt
|
|- project2
|  |- folder1
|     |- folder2
|        |- folder3
|           |- folder4
|              |- even
|                 |- src
|                 |  |- a.foobar.txt
|                 |  |- b.foobar.txt
|                 |  |- c.snafu.txt
|                 |
|                 |- temp
|                    |- a.foobar.txt
|                    |- b.foobar.txt
|                    |- c.snafu.txt
|
|- project3
|  |- odd
|     |- src
|     |  |- a.foobar.txt
|     |  |- b.foobar.txt
|     |  |- c.snafu.txt
|     |
|     |- temp
|        |- a.foobar.txt
|        |- b.foobar.txt
|        |- c.snafu.txt
|
|- project4
   |- even
      |- src
      |  |- a.foobar.txt
      |  |- b.foobar.txt
      |  |- c.snafu.txt
      |
      |- temp
         |- a.foobar.txt
         |- b.foobar.txt
         |- c.snafu.txt
```

The output of the above command is

```
root\project4\even\src\a.foobar.txt
root\project4\even\src\b.foobar.txt
```

However, I was expecting

```
root\project2\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\even\src\a.foobar.txt
root\project2\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\even\src\b.foobar.txt
root\project4\even\src\a.foobar.txt
root\project4\even\src\b.foobar.txt
```

How can I change my command so it also finds the files in the `project2` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was thinking of string match:

```
gci * -R | ? { $_.FullName -like '*\even\src\*.foobar.txt' }
```

Comment: Both solutions work, but I like this one slightly better for its simplicity. Thank you!

Comment: @inejwstine Yes it will work, but may be slower depending on your directory tree. But if this works fine for you - then go for it.

Comment: Agree - it’s not optimised for speed, or memory. I was thinking about readability, mostly.

Answer (score 2):

Break it up into 2 steps. First recurse all the directories, filtering out the ones you want, then pipe that result through another `get-childitem` that filters out the filenames you want:

```
ls -Recurse -Directory | where {$_.FullName -like "*\even\src"} | ls -filter  *.foobar.txt
```